# How to activate function after the keypress?

Tags: javascript, function, search, autocomplete

Im building a autocomplete tool for my website. I want it to search for partial matches (it works only when "*" is the last character)

So I have this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.search-form').click(function () {
           var self = this;
           event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
          

            var searchfield = $('.input-block-level');
            searchfield.val(searchfield.val() + "*");
          
            self.submit();
        });

 </script>
```

What it does is it gives me "*" immediately after clicking in search field and submits.

I need the function that puts the asterisks as the last symbol immediately after clicking (so when person starts typing the "*" is the last character) and waits for person to click submit (or not).

Any ideas anyone?

Please help

Comment: What "java" tag has to do in this question?

Comment: for sure... that is what  $('.search-form').***click*** does! react to a ***click*** event...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the .search-form that is being clicked on is the entire form? So when you click within the search box to type, the entire callback function for your click object is being run, which includes the self.submit().

I think you need to separate the two functionalities into their own event handlers. The searchfield.val(searchfield.val() + "*"); should be run when someone clicks into the $('.input-block-level');, and the submit function should be attached to the submit button itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, if I understood correctly, is an additional event listener for the `keypress` or `keyup` event. But you have to replace the asteriks every time the event fires. Try this:

```js
$('.input-block-level').keypress(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(/[a-z]/ig.test(e.key)) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\*$/g,'') + e.key + '*');
    }
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!! Thank you so much! 
It works!
The small problem is that it works with physical keyboard only, when I type on my mobile it shows "undefined*" - any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Also when I press enter it prints "enter". Is it possible to make this function only for a-z?

Comment: sure, I've editted the solution and added a RegExp. @MarcinStańczyk

Comment: Thanks for the update but it wasn't what I needed. I solved the problem without using java script. 
Thanks again